# Difference between context-switch overhead of Thread.sleep() and wait()

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, context-switch

Context switch takes place when the statements Thread.sleep() or wait() on a semaphore are executed. Is the overhead of context switch is same in both cases? That is, flushing a TLB and restoring registers and stacks etc all steps will be performed in both cases or there is a difference ?

Comment: Probably 0, maybe hardware dependent and certainly not part of the Java spec. The wakeup condition is also information for the scheduler which runs in software and since the scheduler switches between like 1000 threads on a machine anyways I would be very surprised if it would do something special in case you request a change in scheduling vs the regular schedule.